In Apache Isis 1.14.0 I need to overwrite the LogoutLink in the TertiaryActionsPanel HOW?
I need to implement a different authentication strategy for Apache Isis 1.14.0 (i can not update to a newer version currently) also i am forced to use Java 8. I implemented oauth2 with Microsoft Entra and a new shiro realm. But the logout page link is auto generated by wicket in the TeritiaryActionsPanel and uses CssMenuItem.  CssMenuItem <- is private
My Logout Page:
public class CustomLogoutPage extends WebPage {
    public CustomLogoutPage() {
        SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();

        setResponsePage(getApplication().getHomePage());
    }
})

This is the decompiled class with the method addLogoutLink that is generated from the Framework:
public class TertiaryActionsPanel extends Panel {

    public TertiaryActionsPanel(String id, List<CssMenuItem> menuItems) {
        super(id);
        addLogoutLink(this);
        final List<CssMenuItem> subMenuItems = flatten(menuItems);
        final ListView<CssMenuItem> subMenuItemsView = new ListView<CssMenuItem>("subMenuItems", subMenuItems) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<CssMenuItem> listItem) {
                CssMenuItem subMenuItem = listItem.getModelObject();
                if (subMenuItem.hasSubMenuItems()) {
                    addFolderItem(subMenuItem, listItem);
                } else {
                    ServiceActionUtil.addLeafItem(subMenuItem, listItem, TertiaryActionsPanel.this);
                }
            }
        };

        WebComponent divider = new WebComponent("divider") {
            @Override
            protected void onConfigure() {
                super.onConfigure();

                subMenuItemsView.configure();
                setVisible(!subMenuItems.isEmpty());
            }
        };

        add(subMenuItemsView, divider);
    }

    protected List<CssMenuItem> flatten(List<CssMenuItem> menuItems) {
        List<CssMenuItem> subMenuItems = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (CssMenuItem menuItem : menuItems) {
            subMenuItems.addAll(menuItem.getSubMenuItems());
        }
        return subMenuItems;
    }

    private void addLogoutLink(MarkupContainer themeDiv) {
        Link logoutLink = new Link("logoutLink") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                getSession().invalidate();
                setResponsePage(getSignInPage());
            }
        };
        themeDiv.add(logoutLink);
    }

    private Class<? extends Page> getSignInPage() {
        return pageClassRegistry.getPageClass(PageType.SIGN_IN);
    }


    private void addFolderItem(CssMenuItem subMenuItem, ListItem<CssMenuItem> listItem) {
        final MarkupContainer parent = TertiaryActionsPanel.this;
        ServiceActionUtil.addFolderItem(subMenuItem, listItem, parent, ServiceActionUtil.SeparatorStrategy.WITHOUT_SEPARATORS);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);
        response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(new CssResourceReference(TertiaryActionsPanel.class, "TertiaryActionsPanel.css")));
    }

    /**
     * {@link com.google.inject.Inject}ed when {@link #init() initialized}.
     */
    @com.google.inject.Inject
    private PageClassRegistry pageClassRegistry;

This is what I tried:
public class CustomTertiaryMenuBar extends TertiaryActionsPanel {

    @Inject
    public CustomTertiaryMenuBar(String id, List menuItems) {
        super(id, menuItems);
    }


    protected void addLogoutLink(MarkupContainer themeDiv) {
        Link<Void> logoutLink = new Link<Void>("logoutLink") {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                // Redirect to your custom logout page
                setResponsePage(CustomLogoutPage.class);
            }
        };
        themeDiv.add(logoutLink);
    }
}

Overwrite the Factory to create my custom component menu:
public class CustomTertiaryMenuPanelFactory extends TertiaryMenuPanelFactory {

    @Override
    public Component createComponent(final String id, final IModel<?> model) {
        final ServiceActionsModel serviceActionsModel = (ServiceActionsModel) model;
        return new CustomTertiaryMenuBar(id, ServiceActionUtil.buildMenu(serviceActionsModel));
    }
}

I extend the IsisWicketApplication and overwrite the new module method:
...
 @Override
    protected final Module newIsisWicketModule() {
        final Module isisDefaults = super.newIsisWicketModule();
        final Module pythiaOverrides = new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
           // not sure if this is the way
                bind(TertiaryMenuPanelFactory.class).to(CustomTertiaryMenuPanelFactory.class);
            }
        };
        return Modules.override(isisDefaults).with(...);
    }
...

Unfortunately that does not work and the CustomTertiaryMenuPanelFactory createComponent is never called. Could this be done in another way? Did I forget something?
